# Oracle nvl in where clause showing strange results?

Tags: oracle, plsql, nvl

I have a web form that allows users to search on and edit records from an Oracle table based on parameters passed in to a proc. Here's my data:

```
CAE_SEC_ID  SEC_CODE  APPR_STATUS
1           ABC1      100
2           ABC2      100
3           ABC3      101
4           (null)    101
5           (null)    102
6           ABC4      103
```

And here's the where clause:

```
select foo 
  from bar 
 where CAE_SEC_ID = NVL(p_cae_sec_id,CAE_SEC_ID)
   and Upper(SEC_CODE) like '%' || Upper(NVL(p_sec_code,SEC_CODE)) || '%'
   and APPR_STATUS = NVL(p_appr_status, APPR_STATUS)
```

Using nvl on the parameters should return only the matched records if any of the parameters have values, and all records if none of the parameters have values. All pretty standard or so I thought. However when I do a search without any parameter values the query isn't returning records with a null SEC_CODE i.e. only records 1, 2, 3, and 6 are being returned. Shouldn't the where clause above include records with null SEC_CODE values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it shouldn't.

The SEC_CODE in the database is null, so the UPPER(SEC_CODE) is null and so it will fail on a LIKE match or pretty much any other comparison beyond IS NULL. Technically it is a UNKNOWN rather than a FALSE but is isn't enough to pass the test.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `SEC_CODE` value in the table is NULL.  That means that `UPPER(sec_code)` is NULL and your second predicate simplifies to

```
and NULL LIKE '%%'
```

Just like NULL is not equal to anything and not unequal to anything, it is not like anything.  Most likely, you want something like

```
and (Upper(SEC_CODE) like '%' || Upper(NVL(p_sec_code,SEC_CODE)) || '%' or
     (sec_code is null and p_sec_code is null))
```

That will return every row if `P_SEC_CODE` is NULL but still apply the filter if `P_SEC_CODE` is non-NULL.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `NULL`, which is not `true` and so these rows won't be returned. If I understand the requirement correctly, you only want to filter if a parameter is different from null, so I would rewrite the query like this to make the filter more explicit:

```
select foo from bar 
where (p_cae_sec_id is null or CAE_SEC_ID = p_cae_sec_id)
and (p_sec_code is null or Upper(SEC_CODE) like '%' || Upper(p_sec_code) || '%')
and (p_appr_status is null or APPR_STATUS = p_appr_status)
```

Setting the p_sec_code parameter to null will now return all rows, ignoring the value in the SEC_CODE column.

Answer (score 0):

We can also write the Jorn's query like

```
select foo from bar 
where (CASE WHEN p_cae_sec_id is null THEN 'Y'
            WHEN CAE_SEC_ID = p_cae_sec_id THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N'
                    END)='Y'
and   (CASE WHEN p_sec_code is null THEN 'Y'
            WHEN Upper(SEC_CODE) like '%' || Upper(p_sec_code) || '%' THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N'
                    END)='Y'
and (CASE WHEN p_appr_status is null THEN 'Y'
                    WHEN APPR_STATUS = p_appr_status THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
                END)='Y'
```

to make it concrete and increase the performance .

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate on why this increases the performance?